# Build select query with json data

Tags: javascript, c#, json

Hi i want to build select query with json data

json data

```
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "Name": "Group1",
      "Fields": [
        {
          "Field": "EmployeeSCP.Salary",
          "Operator": "lt",
          "Value": "50000"
        }
      ],
      "Condition": "0"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Group2",
      "Fields": [
        {
          "Field": "EmployeeSCP.Salary",
          "Operator": "gt",
          "Value": "20000"
        }
      ],
      "Condition": "0"
    },
  ],
  "groupCondition": 0
}
```

my model

```
public class ValidationModelData
{
    public List<Data> Data { get;set; }
    public string groupCondition { get; set; }
}

public class FieldsData
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<FieldsData> Fields { get; set; }
    public string Condition { get; set; }
}
```

using this I want to build select query like this

```
select * from EmployeeSCP where salary < 50000 AND salary>20000
```

anyone please tell me

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to deserialize that data. There is a great library for that, `Json.Net`.

```
string json = ""; //your json string
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ValidationModelData>(json);
```

Then you can use **Linq** to select the objects you like with an SQL like syntax:

```
var result = from d in data
             where d.Name == "TestName"
             select d;
```

You can achieve the same using method syntax:

```
var result = data.Where(d => d.Name == "TestName");
```

PS: I cannot give an example with `salary`, because the given classes do not have this property.